When i tried to open andtiod studio i get error :C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
I can not open android studio because when I tried to open android studio I get an internal error like this (Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
how I can solve this plz?
when I tried to open andriod studio , this error occurred

My first suggestion is to uninstall completely, then reinstall. My second suggestion is to file a support request with JetBrains.

You don't need to install the SDK completely before that you can go to settings and then check you JRE path and then just cross check if it exists there or not.
If not open application in Android studio and it will guide you to install and update the JRE if required.
Just try to compile your application in Android studio it gives better suggestion and solutions if it's related to Android
Hope this helps
